# How to get the rows which contain a specific words?

Tags: python, pandas, extract, python-re

I'm using netfilx [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/victorsoeiro/netflix-tv-shows-and-movies). uploaded by VICTOR SOEIRO on KAGGLE. I want to make new datasets based on *genres* . For example, I want new dataframe  if *genres* contain word ['comedy'] or ['comedy','fantasy'].

###### My_code

```
df_comedy = df[df['genres'].str.extract("'comedy'")]
```

It gives me this error. **ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups**

Ask me to provide more information, If you don't understand my question.

Thank you.

Comment: Use str.contains instead of extract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Solution for your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
#reading csv file
df = pd.read_csv("Assignment.csv")

# filtering the rows where Credit-Rating is Fair
df = df[df['Credit-Rating'].str.contains('Fair')]
print(df)
```

output:

```
job        Age_Range    Salary    Credit-Rating  Savings    

Own        Middle-aged  High       Fair          10000    
Govt       Young        Low        Fair          15000   
Private    Senior       Average    Fair          20000  
Own        Middle-aged  High       Fair          13000   
Own        oung         Low        Fair          17000
```

Use `contains` instead of `extract`, you will get your answer.